# Inserting data frame via "to_excel" overwrites rest of file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

The following command is erasing every other sheet in "portfolio.xlsx":

```py
df.to_excel("Portfolio.xlsx", sheet_name='base_data', index = False)
```

I just want to update the data in `sheet = 'base_data'`, without changing the rest of the file.

Comment: see the docs for how to append to an existing Excel file rather than overwriting the file: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: This is their example, the mode = 'a' means they are using 'append' mode which won't overwrite existing data: 

with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', mode='a') as writer:  
     df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_3')